# Has Embedded property of notes document class will work in mac OS

Tags: lotus-notes

I need to provide a rich text field but should not allow the user to append any attachment. When i tried using has embedded property to validate the above scenario. Will this property will work in Mac OS. I have seen in help document that it is not supported in Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Note: Embedded objects and object links are not supported for OS/2, UNIX, and the Macintosh. File attachments are."

It means that on macOS you can only append a file as attachment.
Call notesRichTextItem .EmbedObject(  EMBED_ATTACHMENT ,  "" ,  FileFullPath)

You can't append embeded "word-form" or "Excel-sheet" or "anything else", only file as attachment. And it's work.
Also you can use Formula (UI and Edit mode only): @Command( [EditInsertFileAttachment] )

This is restricted operation, user will see ECL-alert message.

Comment: To clarify Paul's answer: hasEmbedded is for both OLE objects and file attachments. It works fine on the Mac for file attachments. but OLE objects don't work on the Mac so hasEmbedded ignores them.